# What is causing to JUnit and System Rules to fail on this Student's Submission?

Tags: java, junit, system-rules

I've been working off an automatic grader for the past month and one of my students that understands the material seems to continually fail my JUnit test cases due to returning 'null'. Since it is a Java I course, they are still using `System.out.println()` for the time being. Because of this, I'm using [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) to parse their outputs.

Student's Submission:

```
import  java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceFormula {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declarations
    double distance;
    double differenceX;
    double differenceY;
    double firstX;
    double secondX;
    double firstY;
    double secondY;

    //User Input for the First X value (X value for Point 1)
    System.out.println("Enter In The value of X for point 1:");
    Scanner inputFirstX = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstX = inputFirstX.nextDouble();

    //User Input for the First Y value  (Y value for Point 1)
    System.out.println("Enter In The value of Y for point 1:");
    Scanner inputFirstY = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstY = inputFirstY.nextDouble();

    //User Input for Second X value (X value for point 2)
    System.out.println("Enter In The value of X for point 2:");
    Scanner inputSecondX = new Scanner(System.in);
    secondX = inputSecondX.nextDouble();

    //User Input for Second Y value (Y value for point 2)
    System.out.println("Enter In The value of Y for point 2:");
    Scanner inputSecondY = new Scanner(System.in);
    secondY = inputSecondY.nextDouble();

    //Find the difference of each point
    differenceX = secondX - firstX;
    differenceY = secondY - firstY;

    //Distance Formula
    distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(differenceX, 2)) + (Math.pow(differenceY, 2)));

    //Displaying the outcome
    System.out.println("Your First Point: " + firstX + "," + firstY + "\n" + "Your Second Point: " + 
    secondX + "," + secondY + "\n"  + "The distance between the two points is: " + distance);
     }
}
```

One of my Test Cases:

```
@Rule
public final StandardOutputStreamLog outlog = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

@Rule
public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();
...
@Test(timeout=5000)
public void tests1() {
    double x1 = 5.0;
    double y1 = 5.0;
    double x2 = 4.5;
    double y2 = 4.5;
    systemInMock.provideText(x1+"\n"+y1+"\n"+x2+"\n"+y2+"\n");
    TestFile.main(new String[]{});
    String reality = outlog.getLog().toLowerCase();
    double calc = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    boolean result = reality.contains(calc+"");
    assertTrue("Testing "+x1+" "+y1+" "+x2+" "+y2+" ", result);
}
```

Finally, my TestRunner:

```
// JUnit
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

// SimpleJSON
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

public class TestRunner {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);

        double tests = result.getRunCount();
        double fails = result.getFailureCount();
        obj.put("tests", tests);
        obj.put("fails", fails);

        //System.out.println("Testing Complete\n---------------------------");
        //System.out.printf("Run Time of Tests:\t%d ms\n", result.getRunTime());
        //System.out.printf("Number of Tests:\t%d\n", (int)tests);

        if (result.wasSuccessful()){
            //System.out.println("All Tests Successful");
        } else {
            //System.out.println("Test Fails\n---------------------------");
            JSONArray failures = new JSONArray();
            System.out.printf("Number of Fails:\t%d\n", (int)fails);
            for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                String header = failure.getTestHeader();
                String msg = failure.getMessage();
                if (msg.contains("timed out")){
                    failures.add(header + " " + msg);
                    System.out.println(header + " " + msg);
                } else {
                    failures.add(msg);
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
                obj.put("failures", failures);
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("Results\n---------------------------");
        double grade = 100.0 * (double)((tests - fails)/tests);
        obj.put("grade", grade);
        System.out.printf("Grade:\t\t\t%.1f%%\n", grade);
        System.out.print("JSON:\n");
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

In the TestRunner `if (msg.contains("timed out"))` will error out because msg is `null`.

If I run the student's code or test anyone else's work, the Tests run perfectly fine. If it is something on my end, I'd like to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try working with failure.getException() to find out more?

Comment: I'm messing with his code as my other test cases run and changed it to `String str = failure.toString();` instead of the `getTestHeader()` and `getMessage()`. My output is ""tests1(TestJunit): null".

Comment: My thoughts are that it resides with his implementation of multiple Scanner objects since his output of the TestRunner is `Enter In The value of X for point 1:
Enter In The value of Y for point 1:
Enter In The value of X for point 1:
Enter In The value of Y for point 1:`

Comment: It's definitely caused by the multiple ```Scanner``` objects. Modifying the student's code to re-use the same scanner causes the test to succeed.

Comment: @AdamG. I'm the maintainer of System Rules. It is a very special problem but I try to fix it in System Rules.

Comment: @StefanBirkner Thanks! I was not sure if it was a bug that was worthy to be submitted via github. Glad I could break it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in System Rules 1.11.0. You have to provide multiple lines:

```
systemInMock.provideLines(
  Double.toString(x1),
  Double.toString(y1),
  Double.toString(x2),
  Double.toString(y2));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` is buffered, so each constructed instance is consuming more of the text from the mocked `System.in` than just what's needed for `nextDouble`. The next `Scanner` tries to read what's left from the same underlying stream but the input has already been consumed so `nextDouble` throws `NoSuchElementException`.

You could try to more accurately mock `System.in` by returning fewer bytes (but not indicating the end of the stream) until the next call to `System.out` is detected, or change approach and use `Runtime.exec` to spawn a new JVM and capture all output from that process.